# Sticky side bar component won't stick to the top - React + SCSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I have a nav bar component coded in my React app's JSX with a class of `column-left`:

```
<animated.div className="column-left" style={anim}>
                            <div className="top">
                                <img src={logo} alt="quicknote" style={{ height: "200px" }}/>
                                <h1>Hello, {user.firstName}</h1>
                                <button id="new-note"><span>+</span> New Note</button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="bottom">
                                <button onClick={() => setAcctSettingsVis(true)}>Account Settings</button>
                                <button onClick={handleClick}>Log Out</button>
                            </div>
</animated.div>
```

And I'm then targeting that element with the class name in my SCSS and applying the `position: sticky` attributes as well as a `top` position of 0 to tell it where to stick:

```
.column-left {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        min-width: 20rem;

        //...
}
```

But when main content of my page extends beyond the window view height and I scroll down, the nav bar does not stick. I'm confused because I've used this set up on other projects before and it worked just fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: sticky wont work if you have used overflow hidden in  any of the parent component please check that

Comment: Ah-ha, that was the fix. The more you know. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help...

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a css (or scss) file that has this code snippet:

```
.fixed-top {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1030;
}
```

You could then attach the **fixed-top** attribute to one of your tags. Once you do this, you might have to add some top padding or bottom padding to your content (sometimes it will get covered), but nonetheless, this is a solution that should work!